# Killing a single process from multiple processes under ntauthority

Tags: windows, process

We currently have a few processes running with the same image name: w3wp.exe.

One of them has a memory leak, so until the dev guys plug that we're wanting to run a scheduled task to kill the process before the RAM runs out on the server.

I've been using:

taskkill /F /FI "MEMUSAGE gt 5000000" /IM "w3wp.exe"

That kills the process whenever memory usage is > 5GB. I've been running this as a scheduled task every 5 minutes.

This works, but it also kills the other instances of w3wp.exe. They're all running under NTAUTHORITY.

My question is, is there a way of isolating a single process from where multiple processes are running under the same image name?

Does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Cheers,

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following in a batch file:

```
@echo off
set tmpfile=%tmp%\tasklist~.txt

tasklist /FI "MEMUSAGE gt 5000000" | FIND "w3wp.exe" > "%tmpfile%"
for /F "tokens=2*" %%i in (%tmpfile%) do @taskkill /f /PID %%i

del %tmpfile%
```

Edit: actually, there is an even better way:

First, you need to isolate the app in its own apppool. Then you just issue the following command:
    %windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool "MyApplicationPool"

(use %windir%\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list apppool to get the name if necessary)

That should recycle the app gracefully (unless it's really stuck).